# Significado de "ah re"

Tags: expresiones, significado, argentina

Soy de Argentina, y veo que siempre dicen

> ah re

justo después de decir una tontería.

¿Harán referencia a montar caballos?

Comment: puedes agregar un ejemplo de en que caso utilizan el "ah re" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En Argentina usamos "ah re" como una expresión que da a entender que uno dijo una tontería, una exageración o algo que no debe ser tomado con seriedad o en sentido literal.

Por ejemplo:

> El otro día hice un gol como el de Maradona a los ingleses pero dos
>   veces mejor. Ah re.

o

> Ah re que ahora con esas zapatillas saltás y salís al espacio.

Espero que se entienda un poco más.

Answer (score 12):

En Argentina se usa por la gente joven (adolescentes) en el ambiente informal.

El *ah re* se puede entender como la afirmación de que uno dijo una tontería. Se usa por ejemplo en:

> Ahora sale volando, ah re jaja.

Generalmente es como para que la gente se ría. También:

El *re* en los contextos anteriores es una acortación de *Ah, re boludo* (Boludo signfica `tonto`, `estúpido`, `payaso`). `Re` es similar a `muy`, como por ejemplo: *uh, está re loco* o *está volando re alto*.

Se pueden ver diversas maneras de escribirlo: *ahre, arre, are*. La manera normal es *ah re* (para cuando está al final de una oración).

También se usa al inicio de una oración:

> —Pepe me dijo que fue a un recital y estabas vos.
>
> —Ah, re que lo que dijo es mentira.

> —Me encantan mis flores amarillas!
>
> —Ah, re que tus flores ni son amarillas.

pero en este contexto no significa que es algo tonto, sino que es como uno potencia la afirmación de que lo que está a continuación.

Comment: Entiendo, también puede aparecer al principio de la oración.

Answer (score 5):

Es una expresión que se deformó con el tiempo, originalmente se usaba en frases como:

> Éramos las mas lindas de la fiesta; ah, ¡re creídas las chicas!
>
> Cada vez que intento algo nuevo me sale bien; ah, re exagerado el chabón

Había una afirmación, y luego su negación en tercera persona. Como si lo dijese otra persona desmintiendo a la primera.

Pero con el tiempo, estos mocosos modernos (millenials) lo empezaron a usar de forma recortada, sin sentido y sin siquiera saber porqué.

[alguna pavada]: ah re

Si decís "ah re" es porque no te haces cargo de la pavada que dijiste.

Más claro, ¡échale agua!

Comment: Perfecta explicación. Siempre que se explique algo de lunfardo, hay que ponerle la proveniencia y evolución o no entiende nada. Ahora efectivamente no puede ser más claro.

Answer (score 2):

Solo falta aclarar que el "re" corresponde a un aumentativo. Es decir si una chica es **re**-linda, quiere decir que es **muy** linda.
Toda la genealogía de la expresión sería, siempre en tono irónico :
"Juego re-bien, como Maradona" =>
"Juego como Maradona, ah re-bien juego" =>
"Juego como Maradona, ah re-bien juega el chavon" =>
"Juego como Maradona, ah re.